# Including html parts in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html

I am writing web site using ASP.net, and I want to seperate my pages into some logical HTML parts (menus, panels, etc.). 
When it comes to parts that have a server logic, the obvious solution is to use UserControl, but most of the parts on my site, have client side logic only, i.e javascript and HTML. 
Recently I found out that it's possible to include parts by using the code: 

        `<% Response.WriteFile ("MyPart.html") %>`


So my question is: what is the better way to do it? should I write a UserControl for each one of my parts, or should I user `Resonse.WriteFile (...)` for my non-server-side logic parts?

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to [master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx), they allow you to apply templates to your site.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to get away from using `Response.WriteFile` and in your case you should probably go with a combination of Master Pages and UserControls. The Master page will define the structure of all your site pages and such things as CSS and JavaScript files.

Within the Master Pages you can, esp. if your parts are dynamic e.g. a navigation menu that changes depending on where you are in the site) write these as UserControls and include them in your Master page markup definition.

Here's a simplified version of what I mean:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link ... />
        <script type='text/jscript' href='/myjs.js' ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <uc1:TopMenu id='topMenu' .. /><!-- A usercontrol that generates the top menu -->
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id='cphBody'>

        <asp:/ContentPlaceholder/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know about master pages, and it's not the case. I simply want to seperate parts in different files for reusing in pages with different master pages.
Why shoyldn't I use Response.WriteFile?

Comment: Response.WriteFile is intended for serving files rather than building pages.

UserControls and Custom Controls are what you need to encapsulate functionality that you can then re-use throughout your site. If you want to get more specialised, you could look at ASP.Net MVC further down the line.